# Rewrite / PrettyFaces with parameter causes IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces, ocpsoft-rewrite

I want to use some url rewriter with annotations in my JSF 2.2 application, so I've started to play around with `Rewrite` (`PrettyFaces` successor).

My application is still just an hello world running in `TomEE` 7.x, no fancy dependencies here, I guess. I run with no `web.xml`, empty `faces-config.xml` and empty `beans.xml`.

I've created a new dedicated backing bean and xhtml to test `Rewrite`, the problem is whenever I add a parameter in the Url, I get a `IllegalStateException`: *Cannot create a session after the response has been committed*

I've tried to downgrade to `PrettyFaces` 3.3.3 but exactly the same error occurs.

Here is the code of the Backing Bean

```
@Named
@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
@URLMapping(id = "testroot", pattern = "/testRoot/#{testRootView.bar}", viewId = "xyz/TestRoot.jsf")
public class TestRootView implements Serializable {

    String foo = "my first String";

    String bar ="";

    // getters and setters ...
}
```

and the view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body jsf:id="root-body" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">

<p>
This is my string : #{testRootView.foo}
</p>

<p>
And this is another string : #{testRootView.bar}
</p>

</body>
```

and the stack trace when I access `http://localhost:8080/testRoot/aaa`

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the
>   response has been committed
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2952)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2361)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:896)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:231)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:231)
>     org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.SessionMap.setAttribute(SessionMap.java:56)
>     org.apache.myfaces.util.AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.put(AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.java:109)
>     org.apache.myfaces.util.AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.put(AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.java:38)
>     org.apache.myfaces.application.viewstate.ServerSideStateCacheImpl.saveSerializedViewInServletSession(ServerSideStateCacheImpl.java:250)
>     org.apache.myfaces.application.viewstate.ServerSideStateCacheImpl.saveSerializedView(ServerSideStateCacheImpl.java:642)
>     org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlResponseStateManager.saveState(HtmlResponseStateManager.java:138)
>     org.apache.myfaces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:279)
>     org.apache.myfaces.shared.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.renderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:220)
>     org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:313)
>     com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
>     javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:58)
>     javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:58)
>     org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.renderView(OmniViewHandler.java:115)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:116)
>     org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:267)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:200)
>     org.apache.tomee.myfaces.TomEEWorkaroundFacesServlet.service(TomEEWorkaroundFacesServlet.java:47)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
>     com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)

Note that if I remove the parameter from the pattern (`pattern = "/testRoot"`) and I access `http://localhost:8080/testRoot` there is no problem and the view is well rendered.

What am I doing wrong ? (I've given the version with prettyfaces, I can give the one with Rewrite's `@Join` too, but I think the problem is elsewhere as the error is the same...)

Comment: Could you double check that the `viewId` attribute is correct? You should also use an absolute viewId (like `/xyz/TestRoot.jsf`). You could also try to alter the pattern by appending a slash (`/testRoot/#{testRootView.bar}/`) because some contains have pretty weird behavior in some corner cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [chkal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395181/chkal), I found the issue, it was indeed the lack of root ('/') in the `viewId` field (or the `to` field in the `Rewrite` version).

Adding it solved this problem. I'm still wondering where my code were going to search for a session for that, and what it would have done if it had found one :)

Comment: I guess the "session problem" is actually cause by the fact that Rewrite forwards the request to an invalid path. May be failed forwards aren't handle correctly somewhere. :-)